# Why echo function print data in console?

Tags: php, html, ajax, echo

I'm creating page in PHP but when I use AJAX to send data, echo function start to printing data in console instead in DOM elements.

I want to add Quagga barcode reader to my page. Quagga is write in JS but my page is in php. So I have to use Ajax to send barcode result to my php code. And there is a problem. After sending data (POST) and using `echo` to display that on the screen, every data that echo should display are showing up in console. Not only data I send but whole page html code too. Even `header('Location: ')` doesn't work correctly. Because I'm sending readed code to `barcodereaded.php` where I put POST data inside `SESSION` var, and I try to echo that on the screen in different file `barcoderesult.php` but everytime data is printed in console log in `barcode.php` (which code is below). On every other subpage php echo and header functions works fine, only this one case causing troubles.

```
<div id="scanner-container"></div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Start/Stop" />

<script src="js/quagga.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var _scannerIsRunning = false;

    function startScanner() {


        var barcode = {};
        Quagga.init({
            inputStream: {
                name: "Live",
                type: "LiveStream",
                numOfWorkers: navigator.hardwareConcurrency,
                target: document.querySelector('#scanner-container'),
                constraints: {
                    size: 1920,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 480,
                    facingMode: "environment"
                },
            },
            config: {
                frequency: 5,
            },
            locator: {
                patchSize: "x-large",
            },
            decoder: {
                readers: [
                    "code_128_reader",
                    "ean_reader",
                    "ean_8_reader",
                    "code_39_reader",
                    "code_39_vin_reader",
                    "codabar_reader",
                    "upc_reader",
                    "upc_e_reader",
                    "i2of5_reader"
                ],
                debug: {
                    showCanvas: true,
                    showPatches: true,
                    showFoundPatches: true,
                    showSkeleton: true,
                    showLabels: true,
                    showPatchLabels: true,
                    showRemainingPatchLabels: true,
                    boxFromPatches: {
                        showTransformed: true,
                        showTransformedBox: true,
                        showBB: true
                    }
                }
            },

        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return
            }

            console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
            Quagga.start();

            // Set flag to is running
            _scannerIsRunning = true;
        });

        Quagga.onProcessed(function (result) {
            var drawingCtx = Quagga.canvas.ctx.overlay,
            drawingCanvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.overlay;

            if (result) {
                if (result.boxes) {
                    drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("width")), parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("height")));
                    result.boxes.filter(function (box) {
                        return box !== result.box;
                    }).forEach(function (box) {
                        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(box, { x: 0, y: 1 }, drawingCtx, { color: "green", lineWidth: 2 });
                    });
                }

                if (result.box) {
                    Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.box, { x: 0, y: 1 }, drawingCtx, { color: "#00F", lineWidth: 2 });
                }

                if (result.codeResult && result.codeResult.code) {
                    Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.line, { x: 'x', y: 'y' }, drawingCtx, { color: 'red', lineWidth: 3 });
                }
            }
        });


        Quagga.onDetected(function (result) {
            Quagga.stop();
            barcode.code = result.codeResult.code;
            $.ajax({
                url: "barcodereaded.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: barcode,
                success: function(res){
                    console.log(res);
                }

            });
        });
    }

    // Start/stop scanner
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (_scannerIsRunning) {
            Quagga.stop();
            _scannerIsRunning = false;
        } else {
            startScanner();
        }
    }, false);
</script>
```

I just want to send readed barcode to other file to convert it into data I want to add to database (quantity of elements on the pallet, production date, etc.)

Comment: could you add a js fiddle for  this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this part of your code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "barcodereaded.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: barcode,
    success: function(res){
        console.log(res);
    }

});
```

The `success` method tells what to do with the result of your ajax code.
And here you specifically tell to log the response (res) to the console.

Instead you can use the content of `res` to append it to your dom via your preferred Javascript solution (vanilla, jQuery,...).

With jQuery you could (if the result from your php code is some text):

```
$('#my-return-container').text(res)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! JS is not my thing and this project is my way to learn some advance php coding.

Comment: Yep, JS can be tricky when you're not used to, I've been there too!
If it works for you don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @MarcinRadczyk don't forget to valid the answer if the problem is solved.

Comment: answer is valid now, I'm sorry I forgot